# Hiding the browser link in HTML emails (when viewing in browser)

Tags: html, email, browser, hyperlink, hidden

I am using Gold Lasso to send emails to customers and there is a built in functionality to add a link to view the email in a browser.  When the user clicks the link and is viewing the email in their default browser, I would like the "View in browser" link to disappear.

What is the best way to hide that link in the browser, but still have it show up when viewing in any email client?

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function that makes it disappear.

Can't recommend hiding things like this though.
What if you just make it unobtrusive (put it under signature at end of mails)